# For ever and forever

Tags: meaning, grammar, adverbs

What is the difference between the meaning and usage of *for ever* and *forever* in British English? From what I could gather from my online research,

> *forever* means :
>
> 1. (also for ever) for all future time; for always
> 2. continually

and

> *for ever* - Oxford has only Eng-Ger, Eng-It and Eng-Sp entries for it(apart from being redirected to forever's definition), Collins says it is an adverb meaning *forever*.

Comment: _Forever_ meaning “constantly” is only one sense of the word in American English, and far from the most common. We use it more to mean “eternity” or “a long time.” See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forever#Usage_notes for a discussion of British vs American usage.

Comment: Those do not look like quotes from a dictionary. Those look like (poorly punctuated) quotes from random dudes off the Internet. I wonder why nobody ever uses [a dictionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forever) anymore. Dictionaries were precisely invented for the whole purpose of looking up the meanings of words; random dudes were not.

Comment: Good question. Perhaps GR on ELU, but can be asked on ELL ell.stackexchange.com -- *Forever* is **not** *for ever* in all contexts in BrE. They mean different things. For one, the **phrase** has the preposition *for* as in any similar phrase for the needed prepositional sense. The **word** *forever* is used as an adverb or adjective/ noun. Suggested migration to ELL.

Comment: "If only the grieving for Lady Thatcher could go on for ever and ever" (guardian.co.uk); "You'll remember great teaching for ever!" (http://www.mmu.ac.uk/news/news-items/2021/)

Comment: @Kris The dictionary says for ever is an adverb too.

Comment: This conversation has now moved here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/for-ever-and-forever

Comment: Tanvi, yes, it can be an adverbial phrase.